# When appending data to RichTextBox from a TextBox1_TextChanged field, part of my code auto-adds a redudant date. Something wrong with the logic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

What I'm trying to do is to automatically add whatever is scanned to TextBox1 field to RichTextBox1 and then clear the TextBox1 field, but when TextBox1 is cleared, `RichTextBox1.AppendText(scanData + " " + currentTime + vbLf)` takes action and adds a space + TimeOfDay. So the outputs to RichTextBox1 are coming like this:

```
011546 1:30 PM
 1:30 PM
011879 1:31 PM
 1:31 PM
```

**How do I get rid of the redundant secondary time that is inserted in the new line?** Here is my current code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim scanData As String = TextBox1.Text

    Dim currentTime As String = TimeOfDay

    TextBox1.Text = scanData

    RichTextBox1.AppendText(scanData + " " + currentTime + vbLf)

    TextBox1.Clear()

End Sub
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an if statement like this in order to avoid the `RichTextBox1.AppendText(scanData + " " + currentTime + vbLf)` takes place when TextBox1 is cleared.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim scanData As String = TextBox1.Text

    Dim currentTime As String = TimeOfDay

    TextBox1.Text = scanData

    If (TextBox1.Text <> "") Then RichTextBox1.AppendText(scanData + " " + currentTime + vbLf)

    TextBox1.Clear()
End Sub
```

Excuse any gramatical mistakes.

Comment: That if statement is exactly what I was looking for. Can't believe I couldn't wrap my head to come to that conclusion. Thanks a bunch.